# Android: how to use BaseAdapter class without having a nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I understand that many of you are already fed up with the nullpointerexception-related questions, so I thought again and again whether or not to ask this question. I read up the following short code for an hour, and I still cannot figure out why the nullpointerexception is thrown..

Here is the ImageAdapter class..

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_addprofile, null);
            convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(90, 90));

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryText);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryimage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.icon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        holder.icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        holder.icon.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        holder.title.setText(categoryContent[position]);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;
    }

    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery, android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera
    };

    private String[] categoryContent = {
        "Gallery", "Camera"
    };
}
```

And here's the part of the logcat.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.marshall.thequizshow.ui.adapter.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:56)
```

According to the logcat, the end part below the if-else statement in the getView method seems to have the problem. I tried really hard to figure out what should be fixed, but I'm still lost. Somebody please help me?

Comment: "the end part below the if-else statement in the getView method seems to have the problem" -- there are five lines after the `else`. Which **specific** line is triggering the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You can add println statements to figure out what exactly is null (and then make sure it isn't)...

Comment: @CommonsWare According to the logcat, it is only pointing at the first line of the five, but I don't think it's only the first one that's only the problem. Maybe the entire five are throwing the exception..

Comment: Either `holder` is `null` (though it shouldn't be) or `holder.icon` is `null` (e.g., there is no widget in the layout named `R.id.categoryimage`). Use a debugger or `Log` statements to determine which is `null`.

Comment: Please add your imports to find the exact line throwing null

Answer (score 0):

Add  this line in your `constructor`

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```